# How to make each image in a carousel clickable and pointing to a different URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I need to make each image in carousel to be click able and point to separate urls. Any suggestions as how could I achieve it?

My HTML -

```
<ul id="flexiselDemo3">
            <li><img src="images/1.jpg" height='100' width='150' /><a href="http://"></a></li>
            <li><img src="images/2.jpg" height='100' width='150' /><a href="http://"></a></li>
            <li><img src="images/3.jpg" height='100' width='150' /><a href="http://"></a></li>
            <li><img src="images/4.jpg" height='100' width='150' /><a href="http://"></a></li>                                                 
        </ul>
```

How to make each image click able? I am unable to fit anchor tag as such.

Comment: For starters, you should probably be wrapping the `<a>` tag around the `<li>` not nested inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wrap you image with the following anchor tag

```
 <li>
    <a href="http://your link">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" height='100' width='150' />
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Awesome Rex. Thanks a bunchhhhhhhh.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap you image with anchor tag

```
<ul id="flexiselDemo3">
    <li>
        <a href="http://somedomain.com">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" height='100' width='150' />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://somedomain1.com">
            <img src="images/2.jpg" height='100' width='150' />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://somedomain2.com">
            <img src="images/3.jpg" height='100' width='150' />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://somedomai3.com">
            <img src="images/4.jpg" height='100' width='150' />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @anujin what are you not getting here, how the anchor link works

Comment: Sorry, but I believe it got edited to what I saw earlier. Its pretty clear and works. Thanks.

Comment: @anujin, zafar only added `somedomain*.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="flexiselDemo3">
            <li><a href="http://"><img src="images/1.jpg" height='100' width='150' /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://"><img src="images/2.jpg" height='100' width='150' /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://"><img src="images/3.jpg" height='100' width='150' /></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://"><img src="images/4.jpg" height='100' width='150' /></a></li>                                                 
        </ul>
```